# ajax call will be executed fully if page is reloaded?

Tags: ajax

I have a one question.
In the page, I send an ajax call, and immediately reload the page, the ajax call will be fully run?
What about if I close the browser?

Thanks

Comment: Any requests made by a webpage are aborted when that webpage is unloaded (when the user navigates away or closes the window, for example).

Comment: It all depends on whether or not the ajax request finished sending or not. If it finished sending, it's likely the server will process it. It's likely more common though that the abort would happen before it's done sending.

Comment: @KevinB so what you mean is, once ajax request is delivered to server, no matter web page is unloaded or even browser closed, the request is process in Server? It s different theory than sdgluck's commen... which would be correct?

Comment: No, they are quite the same. Sending a request to the server is NOT instant, it could take anywhere from 2ms to 60 seconds depending on network speed and the amount of data being sent. or much longer if you're uploading.

Comment: @KevinB yeah, it takes some time until request is sent to the server, but let say, if its really sent, then it will be processed on server no matter web page state in the client, I am asking.